# Numbering the group after group by column in R

Tags: r, group-by

I want to label number in the same group.I want to group by `date` then give number in the same group.

Here is my data sample:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("RM125","RM126","RM121","RM120","RM128","RM129","RM131","RM133","RM135","RM132"),
                 date = c(rep("1110101",6),rep("1110102",4)))
```

Deisre Output like:

```
ID          Date  label
RM125    1110101      1
RM126    1110101      1
RM121    1110101      1
RM120    1110101      1
RM128    1110101      1
RM129    1110101      1
RM131    1110102      2
RM133    1110102      2
RM135    1110102      2
RM132    1110102      2
```

I have tried many code like

[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099010/r-add-a-dplyr-group-label-as-a-number)
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58722215/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-label-for-groups-of-individuals-rather-than-labels-for-e)
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58735437/how-can-i-label-categories-sequentially-by-group-in-r)

```
df %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(row_number())
df %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(group = match(date, unique(date)))
```

Still can't work.Any tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `cur_group_id()`?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
mutate(group = cur_group_id(), .by = date)
```